# Make a random node , the first node

Tags: c, list

So , i am trying to create a function that takes a linked list and an integer x  as parameters , and searches the list for that x and when it finds it , makes the node that contains it head of the list and returns the place where it found x, this is what i have created so far but the results it gives are wrong

```
int searchMF(list &l,int x){
 node *curr,*temp;
 curr=l.front;
 temp=curr;
 int i,place=0;
 if (l.front->info == x ) return 1;
 else{
 FOR (i,1 TO size(l)) {
   if (curr->info == x) {
      temp->next=curr->next;
      curr->next=l.front;
      place=i;
      break;
   }
   temp=curr;
   curr=curr->next;
 }
 return place;
 }
}
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated

Comment: `int searchMF(list &l,int x)` is a syntax error in C. What is `FOR (i,1 TO size(l))`? Is it supposed to be like BASIC?

Comment: thats actually not a problem because i am coding in a language similar to c that this is not a problem, i am looking for another problem other than syntax (my program compiles normally) thats why the for is different

Comment: @Maverick It would be easier if your source were a complete C program (as tagged) to reproduce its behavior. You may translate it back to your "similar language" once you got a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `curr->next=l.front;` you need to update the `l.front` to point to `curr`.

```
curr->next=l.front;  
l.front = curr;
```

Also pure `C` code would have been more helpful in debugging the problem.